# How to access name space object in parent session in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

this may be a silly question.
I tried to access a table create using shiny module, which is created in a name space, and now I want to read the table from parent session, but I can't figure out how to do this now.

```
ns <- shiny::NS(id)
column(12, DT::DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
```

I try to access the table object("tbl") from parent session
thanks if anyone can help

Comment: Is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708815/accessing-parent-namespace-inside-a-shiny-module what you are looking for?

Comment: @Simon.S.A. Thanks for the link. I realise it's a stupid question, I should create a variable in parent scope and use it in child process. but thanks your comments helped.