# Is there any other than trivial difference between 'getDefaultReactiveDomain()' and 'session' object?

Tags: r, session, shiny

I would like to know if I can use interchangeably `getDefaultReactiveDomain()` with `session` object as a parameter in the server function. In other words: is `getDefaultReactiveDomain()` a function which returns R6 object and `session` is just this R6 object which is returned by `getDefaultReactiveDomain()`?

Let's say, I would like to write a function to reload a web page and I want it to work even if user doesn't include `session` parameter in `server` function:

```
reload <- function() {
  getDefaultReactiveDomain()$reload()
}
```

Can I do it safely? I think that I do not see generally usage of `getDefaultReactiveDomain()$` on Internet (speaking broadly), but `session$`, so I'm afraid it could be not so easy as I think.

MRE:

**getDefaultReactiveDomain**

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

reload <- function() {
  getDefaultReactiveDomain()$reload()
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("reload", "Reload")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    reload()
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$reload)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**session**

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("reload", "Reload")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    session$reload()
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$reload)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to add that in the `shiny` source code I see returned value from `getDefaultReactiveDomain()` as a default value passed to the `session` parameter, for example in this function:

```
shiny::updateActionButton
#> function (session = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), inputId, label = NULL, 
#>     icon = NULL) 
#> {
#>     validate_session_object(session)
#>     if (!is.null(icon)) 
#>         icon <- as.character(validateIcon(icon))
#>     message <- dropNulls(list(label = label, icon = icon))
#>     session$sendInputMessage(inputId, message)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000000001dbdc2a0>
#> <environment: namespace:shiny>
```

So I could be safe using just `getDefaultReactiveDomain()` in my function (**and using it internally, not as a default value for parameter, which user can change**). However, if that's true, why then in `update*` functions from `shiny` other value can be passed to `session` parameter?

Comment: This is because of shiny modules. Inside modules, session domain is different than the top-level session's domain. By default `updateXX` uses current domain, but inside modules, this gives you the option to pass parent session.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708815/accessing-parent-namespace-inside-a-shiny-module) shows exactly how to do what @lz100 explained.