# updateTabItems not working in module if input passed

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to create a function/a module to update tabset items.

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039055/call-updatetabitems-from-inside-shiny-module) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708815/accessing-parent-namespace-inside-a-shiny-module), but my issue relates to how the button input is handled in `updateTabItems`.

Here you can find an example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

mod_updateTabset <- function(
  input, output, session, triggerId, dashboardId, tab, parent
) {
  observeEvent(triggerId, {
    updateTabItems(parent, dashboardId, selected = tab)
  })
}

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = 'Tabs', 
      menuItem("Tab 01", tabName = "tab01", icon = icon("dice-one")),
      menuItem("Tab 02", tabName = "tab02", icon = icon("dice-two"))
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab01",
        actionButton("updateButton", label = "To Tab02")
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab02",
        h4("New Tab")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(
    mod_updateTabset,
    "updateLink",
    triggerId = input$updateButton,
    dashboardId = "Tabs", 
    tab = "tab02",
    parent = session
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know it's working when creating `mod_updateTabset_UI`, shifting the actionButton to the module. That's why I suppose the issue lies in the button handling.

Still, I'd like to have a function/module which can handle all kind of links, buttons etc. to update Tab items, not just one button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into the same problem: You need to use `reactive()` for `triggerId` when calling the module

```r
callModule(
  mod_updateTabset,
  "updateLink",
  triggerId = reactive(input$updateButton),
  dashboardId = "Tabs", 
  tab = "tab02",
  parent = session
)
```

The module then needs to handle a reactive value:

```r
mod_updateTabset <- function(
  input, output, session, triggerId, dashboardId, tab, parent
) {
  observeEvent(triggerId(), {
    updateTabItems(parent, dashboardId, selected = tab)
  })
}
```